# How to debug in Qt Creator under Windows?

Tags: windows, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I want to have the same developing environment either in Linux and in Windows so I decided to use Qt Creator. But for some unknown reason I cannot trace my project in Qt Creator under Windows 7. I compile my program as DEBUG target, the resulting executable contains all debug info. After that I press F10 key to step over main function but instead of stepping it just brings program to run. Stepping into via F11 does the same thing.

Firstly I tried gdb shipped with MinGW but Qt Creator  refused even to run it complaining that it should be Python capable. After that I have downloaded and installed gdb with Python support from

http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/prebuilt/gdb/windows-7/qtcreator-gdb-7.4-MINGW32_NT-6.1-i686.tar.gz

as Qt Creator manual recommends but it just made that Qt Creator is able to start the debugger and nothing more, I could not do source level debugging anyway.

Qt Creator under Linux works fine with the same project, it traces, steps and shows the sources Ok. I run MinGW 4.8.1 and Qt Creator 3.1.1 under Windows 7 64bit and the same Qt Creator 3.1.1 version under Fedora Linux 64bit. How can I achieve source level debugging under Windows like under Linux I do?

Comment: I just install MinGW with the Qt installer or maintenance tool.  It's under the "Tools" heading.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to use Visual studio express compiler and then install the windows debugging tools like specified [here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-debugger-engines.html) and configure qt-creator

Comment: I know about this way. But I want to have the same gcc compiler either in Linux and in Windows so I would like to use MinGW under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Recent GDB builds shipped with MinGW are Python-enabled, and work out-of-the-box in Qt Creator. The link you found seems outdated.